# Android app camera preview stopped working (using deprecated `setType` method)

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a camera app that had a Camera Preview which worked.  The app was developed some years ago (2012) and i decided to reuse parts of its code, but, upon testing again (on same hardware i9100, different OS 4.4 vs 3.0), my camera preview image has a problem

[image]

when i move the phone, i see the image change and it responds to light and dark patterns (therefore app is communicating with camera).

this is my code (it uses deprecated method `setType`):

```
class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "TGCamera";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;
public final String fileName = "/download/CameraGPS/zdelTempPhotoPreview.jpg";

CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open();
    Parameters parameter02 = camera.getParameters();
    parameter02.setJpegThumbnailSize(80, 60);
    parameter02.setPictureSize(640, 480);
    camera.setParameters(parameter02);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        Parameters parameters00 = camera.getParameters();
        //parameters00.setRotation(90);
        //parameters00.setFlashMode("on");
        //parameters00.setJpegQuality(20);
        camera.setParameters(parameters00);

        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                CameraPreview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.

    //camera.getParameters().setRotation();
    //camera.getParameters().setJpegQuality(20);
    //camera.getParameters().setPictureSize(width, height)

    Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    Log.w(TAG,"clicked in preview");
    Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
    Log.d(TAG, "draw");
    canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
            canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot set the picture size and preview size to arbitrary values. Make sure you check the lists returned by getSupportedPictureSizes() and getSupportedPreviewSizes(), respectively. Often (I don't remember if this applies to Samsung Galaxy S2), the camera does not work correctly when the aspect ratio for picture is different from the one for preview. Furthermore, you are not supposed to draw on the preview surface, and definitely not from onPreviewFrame() callback.

Comment: PLEASE supply as answer.  you NAILED IT @AlexCohn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the picture size and preview size to arbitrary values. Make sure you check the lists returned by getSupportedPictureSizes() and getSupportedPreviewSizes(), respectively.

Often (I don't remember if this applies to Samsung Galaxy S2), the camera does not work correctly when the aspect ratio for picture is different from the one for preview.

Furthermore, you are not supposed to draw on the preview surface, and definitely not from onPreviewFrame() callback.

Comment: removed `onDraw` and all references to picture size and it works.  TKS!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing would be to add `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder)` in your `surfaceChanged()` method too

**Update:**
Please debug in `surfaceCreated` and `surfaceChanged` that `holder.getSurface() != null`
Also you should add `camera.release()` in `surfaceDestroyed` and then clean install app (uninstall first and then fresh install the app). The camera service could be hanging since a previous run of the app.

**Update 2:**
I just noticed that you missed registering to callbacks from the `SurfaceHolder` passed by the `surfaceCreated()` and surfaceChanged() methods. In this case it would make sense that surfaceChanged() is never reached and that means startPreview() is never actually called..

In `surfaceCreated` and `surfaceChanged` methods, please update the code to include:

```
    mHolder.removeCallback(this); // unregister from old SurfaceHolder
    holder.addCallback(this); // register to new holder
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mHolder = holder;
```

Comment: unfortunately, did not affect result in the least.  tks 4 the effort, though.  might solve someone else's problem.  :)

Comment: I've updated with more ideas, hoping that it will help get closer to the root cause

Comment: tks again.  yes, releasing camera was a problem, regardless.  still trying to find root problem.  will get to back to u asap.  UPVOTED!

Comment: still no luck.  trying a different approach: will scratch this code and start from the bottom up.

Comment: actually, follwoed AlexCohn's adviceand solved the problem.  luckily, no need to rewrite everything.